# node's position appears constant during physics simulation

Tags: ios, game-physics, scenekit

I'm running some physics on a node. The node moves in all directions, but when tracking it's position it appears to be stationary.

```
func renderer(renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, didSimulatePhysicsAtTime time: NSTimeInterval) {
        print("position.y: \(starNode.position.y)")
```

The message in the debugger is  "position.y: 5.578" (which is the position I assigned in Scene Editor) for every call to **renderer:didSimulatePhysicsAtTime** method

What's going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

that a look at the `presentationNode` property.